# SUM JOIN other table return double value SQL

Tags: sql, group-by, aggregate-functions

I have 2 tables

[image]

Please help me to return result below

[image]

Comment: Please always tag the DBMS you are using!

Comment: Usually it helps if you provide the syntax you have so far.

Answer (score 2):

You can do `JOIN` before doing sum :

```
SELECT p.code,  SUM(p.price) price_total, SUM(s.total) sale_total
FROM Produce p INNER JOIN
     (SELECT ID, SUM(salesoff) as total
      FROM Sale s
      GROUP BY ID
     ) s 
     ON s.ID = p.id
GROUP BY p.code;
```